# C# P-Invoke:how to convert INT fun( BYTE *bStream, UINT16 *nCount, const UINT8 nblk ) to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, pinvoke

With C/C++ DLL SDK fun,like this:

```
    INT CmdGetAllLog( BYTE *bStream, UINT16 *nCount, const UINT8 nblk )
```

but in project use c#,I do it with:

```
    [DllImport("C:\\PrBioApi.dll", EntryPoint = "CmdGetAllLog")]
    private static extern bool CmdGetAllLog(IntPtr bStream, ref UInt16 nCount, byte nblk);
```

and I use it with:

```
                    int nMallocSize = Marshal.SizeOf(new LOG_RECORD()) * stuSystem.wLogCnt + 4096;
                    byte[] pRecord = new byte[nMallocSize];
                    IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(nMallocSize));
                    Marshal.Copy(pRecord, 0, p, pRecord.Length);

                    bGetSucc = CmdGetAllLog(p, ref nGet, nBlk++);

                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
```

but it did not work.
would anyone can help me ?thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code which copies between the managed array, and the unmanaged pointer, is in the wrong place. It would need to be after the call to the unmanaged function.

But you may as well let the p/invoke marshaller do the work for you:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\PrBioApi.dll")]
private static extern bool CmdGetAllLog(
    byte[] bStream, 
    ref ushort nCount, 
    byte nblk
);

int nMallocSize = ...;
byte[] pRecord = new byte[nMallocSize];
bool bGetSucc = CmdGetAllLog(pRecord, ref nGet, nBlk++);
```

Because a byte array is blittable then the marshaller will just pin your array during the call and hand it off to the native code.

I'm assuming that the other two parameters are passed correctly. Since you did not specify any more details of the interface, they could well be wrong. I'd guess that `nGet` is used to tell the function how big the buffer is, and to return how much was copied to it by the function. I cannot see where you specify `nGet` in the question. I'm trusting that you got that bit right.

Some other comments:

1. You may need to specify a calling convention in the `DllImport` attribute. Is the native code `cdecl` perhaps?
2. The return value is `INT` in the native code but you've mapped it to `bool`. That probably is fine if the protocol is that non-zero return means success. But if the return value indicates more than that then you'd clearly need to use `int`. Personally I'd be inclined to use `int` and stay true to the native.

Comment: Yes,it work when remove "ref".3Q.but there is a small problem.

Comment: In fact,we will use C/C++ like: bGetSucc = CmdGetAllLog((BYTE*) (pRecord+nGetCount), &nGet, nBlk++); But i do not know how to ponter "+" in C# .this code should in a while.

Comment: That's a different question with a different answer. You need to provide more detail in the question. No good leaking it out in comments.